# Month function not working with datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the records for 7th month and 2016 year but I'm getting the records for other months and year.Can anyone help?

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 glr.[Creation Date]
    ,gle.[Posting Date]
    ,'Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd'
    ,gle.[User ID]
    ,gle.[G_L Account No_]
    ,gle.[Description]
    ,gle.[Source Code]
    ,sum(gle.Amount)
    ,gle.[Dimension Set ID]
    ,dse.[Dimension Code]
    ,dv.[Code]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN 'Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd' = 'Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd'
            THEN 1
        WHEN 'Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd' = 'Kool Breweries'
            THEN 2
        WHEN 'Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd' = 'Parag Breweries'
            THEN 3
        ELSE 0
        END
    ,gle.[Entry No_]
FROM [INDEL-NVDVCBI02].[VM_CIPL_9Aug_2016_NAV2013R2].dbo.[Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd_$G_L Entry] gle WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [INDEL-NVDVCBI02].[VM_CIPL_9Aug_2016_NAV2013R2].dbo.[Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd_$G_L Register] glr WITH (NOLOCK) ON gle.[Entry No_] = glr.[No_]
INNER JOIN [INDEL-NVDVCBI02].[VM_CIPL_9Aug_2016_NAV2013R2].dbo.[Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd_$Dimension Set Entry] dse WITH (NOLOCK) ON gle.[Dimension Set ID] = dse.[Dimension Set ID]
INNER JOIN [INDEL-NVDVCBI02].[VM_CIPL_9Aug_2016_NAV2013R2].dbo.[Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd_$Dimension Value] dv WITH (NOLOCK) ON dv.[Dimension Code] = dse.[Dimension Code]
WHERE 
    month(gle.[Posting Date]) = cast(7 AS INT)
    AND year([Posting Date]) = cast(2016 AS INT)
    AND dse.[Dimension Code] = 'BRAND'
    OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'COSTCENTER'
    OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'SKU'
    OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'IC'
    OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'REGIONS'
```

Comment: `or` has a lower precedence than `and`. It would be easier to write `dse.[Dimension Code] in ('BRAND', 'COSTCENTER', 'SKU', 'IC', 'REGIONS')`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE 
month(gle.[Posting Date]) = cast(7 AS INT)
AND year([Posting Date]) = cast(2016 AS INT)
AND (dse.[Dimension Code] = 'BRAND'
OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'COSTCENTER'
OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'SKU'
OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'IC'
OR dse.[Dimension Code] = 'REGIONS')
```

The `OR` keyword will otherwise cause that either `month` is 7, `year` is 2016 and `[Dimension Code]` is 'BRAND' **or** `[Dimension Code]` is one of the following values: 'COSTCENTER', 'SKU', 'IC', 'REGIONS'.

Since you are already supplying the list of possible values in your where query you can also write the following:

```
WHERE 
month(gle.[Posting Date]) = cast(7 AS INT)
AND year([Posting Date]) = cast(2016 AS INT)
AND dse.[Dimension Code] IN ('BRAND','COSTCENTER','SKU','IC','REGIONS')
```

This will pull up the same results as the `OR` statements.